# Ubuntu Terminal using bash autocompletes only using alt+tab

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 lts.

When I like to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete any command, i.e `cd /path/to/file`, `vim /path/to/file`, `apt`, etc, pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key itself won't do anything. Instead, if I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it then behaves as I'd like to see.

How can I change the behavior so that pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> alone completes the bash statement?

Answer (score 0):

###### 1. Open the file `/etc/bash.bashrc` by vim to edit it.

```
sudo vim /etc/bash.bashrc
```

###### 2. Find these code

```
#enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#      if [-f  /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#          . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#      elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion]; then
#           . /etc/bash_completion
#      fi
#fi
```

###### 3. Unlock these code by delete '#'

```
#enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
     if [-f  /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
          . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
      elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion]; then
           . /etc/bash_completion
      fi
fi
```

when finished, use `:wq` to save and quit.

###### 4. enable the change by reload it.

```
sudo source /etc/bash.bashrc
```